# Using argparse to parse arguments of form "arg= val"

Tags: python, parsing, command-line, argparse

I want to use argparse to parse command lines of form "arg=val"
For example, the usage would be:

```
script.py conf_dir=/tmp/good_conf
```

To achieve it, I am doing this:

```
desc   = "details"
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=desc, add_help=False)
args = parser.add_argument("conf_dir")
args = parser.parse_args("conf_dir=FOO".split())
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.conf_dir
```

But, the problem is that, on invocation of the script with:

```
python script.py conf_dir=/tmp/good_conf
```

I get:

```
conf_dir=/tmp/good_conf
```

Where as I expect

```
/tmp/good_conf
```

So, the question is: Can I use argparse to parse cmd line, which contains name value pairs?
Any hints?

Edit: The reason I want to do this and not some thing like --conf_dir=/tmp/good_dir is because there are other tools (written in other language), which uses conf_dir=/tmp/good_dir style of arguments.  To maintain consistency, I was to parse args in this way.

Comment: I don't have `argparse` available to check this, but shouldn't `"conf_dir=FOO".split()` actually be `"conf_dir=FOO".split('=')`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse#name-or-flags), `argparse` doesn't natively let you have unprefixed options like that. If you omit the leading `-`, it assumes you are describing a positional argument and expects it to be provided as:

```
python script.py /tmp/good_conf
```

If you want it to be optional, it needs to be correctly marked as a flag by calling it `--conf_dir`, and invoking the script like:

```
python script.py --conf_dir=/tmp/good_conf
```

However, to accept name-value pairs, you can implement a [custom action](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse#action). In combination with `nargs`, such an action could accept an arbitrary number of name-value pairs and store them on the argument parsing result object.

Answer (score 29):

You need a custom action

```
class StoreNameValuePair(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        n, v = values.split('=', 1)
        setattr(namespace, n, v)

args = parser.add_argument("conf_dir", action=StoreNameValuePair)
```

Comment: `str.partition()` is less prone to ValueError than `str.split()` as it always returns three items.

Comment: I'd rather handle that with `values.split('=', 1)`, which doesn't unnecessarily return the `=`. Arguably, you'd *want* a `ValueError` if the name value pair wasn't actually a pair. (Though whether you want to catch the error--or let it propagate upwards--or check if `values.partition("=")[1]` is empty is probably a matter of personal preference.)

Comment: Ok, although `.partition` is built primarily for this use case.  Delimiter can be assigned to `_`, also error can be checked by checking if v is empty.  All without try except.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

@chepner This is great. I improved this to support multiple args as well and store the result as dict:

```
class StoreDict(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        kv={}
        if not isinstance(values, (list,)):
            values=(values,)
        for value in values:
            n, v = value.split('=')
            kv[n]=v
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, kv)
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to put name value pairs on the command line is with options. I.e. you would use

```
python script.py --confdir=/tmp/good_conf
```

argparse can certainly handle that case. See the docs at:

http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#option-value-syntax