# Can argparse accept argument value as key=val pairs

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I am trying to implement below option by using argparse(can't use any other tool like docopt because of project requirement):-

```
cli.py --conf key1=value1, key2=value2, kay3=value3
or
cli.py --conf key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=value3
```

So far I have tried `type=json.loads` or dict but not helping.
One possible solution is to use `type=str` and then later parse it to `dict`. 
Do you guys know any other better solution which I am missing..
Thanks in advance.

Note- Can't use --key1=value1 --key2=value2 --key3=value3 because I don't want to restrict count and name of key/value. It will help in supporting new key/val in future.

Comment: Why not use multiple arguments for `key1` and `key2` etc.?

Comment: Didn't you ask for this, [Using argparse to parse arguments of form “arg= val”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154716/using-argparse-to-parse-arguments-of-form-arg-val). This seems to be helpful to you.

Comment: do you have a constant number of key value pairs? if so, as @OferSadan mentioned, you can just pass them like this `--key1=value1 --key2=value2 --key3=value3`

Comment: 1. There would be other arguments as well, don't want to give option to use key1 and key2 with any other argument
2. Dont want to restrict count and name of key/value pair, If new key/value need to be supported then no changes would be needed in argument parser

Comment: @AlokThakur Please mention those two assumptions in your question to avoid duplication.

Comment: @tiba sorry for confusion, updated question

Answer (score 5):

Since you commented that you must use the cli as it is written, This is another solution. In `argparse` i would define the `conf` argument like this:

```
parser.add_argument('--conf', nargs='*')
```

With `nargs='*'` all the arguments following that would be in the same list which looks like this `['key1=value1', 'key2=value2', 'key3=value3']`

To parse that list and get a dict out of it, you can do this:

```
parsed_conf = {}
for pair in conf:
    kay, value = pair.split('=')
    parsed_conf[key] = value
```

Now call your program like this (without commas):

```
cli.py --conf key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=value3
```

And it should work

Answer (score 2):

I would use `type=str` and parse it later, perhaps with json, but the main problem with that would be the way you are writing your command:

```
cli.py --conf key1=value1, key2=value2, kay3=value3
```

The spaces split each pair to a different argument. If you use either method you suggested it would not work. Instead make sure that they are all one argument:

```
cli.py --conf="key1='value1', key2='value2', kay3='value3'"
```

That way this large argument is ready to be parsed as json

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I feel there should be some way to mention that --conf parameter can take multiple value. I have used such cli which support this.

Comment: There is, I posted another answer to address that