# Named arguments with Python argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to create a terminal application a bit similar to cutechess-cli, which has options like the following:

```
-epdout FILE    Save the end position of the games to FILE in FEN format.
-recover        Restart crashed engines instead of stopping the match
-repeat [N]     Play each opening twice (or N times). Unless the -noswap...
```

which can all be done with `argparse` in Python.

However it also has "named arguments" like the following:

```
-resign movecount=COUNT score=SCORE [twosided=VALUE]
        Adjudicate the game as a loss if an engine's score is
        at least SCORE centipawns below zero for at least COUNT
        consecutive moves.
-sprt elo0=ELO0 elo1=ELO1 alpha=ALPHA beta=BETA
        Use a Sequential Probability Ratio Test as a termination
        criterion for the match. This option should only be used...
```

I can implement that with `argparse` using `nargs='*'` and then writing my own parser (maybe just regex). However that doesn't give nice documentation, and if `argparse` can already do something like this, I would rarther use the builtin approach.

Summary: Does `argparse` have a concept of named arguments similar to `resign` and `sprt` above? And if not, would the best approach be to do this manyally using `nargs='*'`?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, I think you are looking for a [sub-parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands)

Comment: `nargs=3`, and after parsing unpack the list value: `COUNT, SCORE, VALUE = args.resign`.  And write the `help` line as shown.

Comment: While you can do fancy things with `type` and `action`, it's often simpler to fiddle with the values after parsing.

Comment: @Tomerikoo That would give me `cmd.py resign -movecount 40 -score 500 sprt -elo 100 -elo1 200`. I guess that's somehow similar, but I feel subparsers are more commonly used for separate programs, like `git rebase` and `git stash` etc.

Comment: @hpaulj That would work, but then the arguments wouldn't be named. In the documentation that wouldn't matter, but in a long command line, it can be nice to have names.

Comment: There have been previous requests for arbitrary `key=value` pairs, with similar advise - parse them yourself.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/45025414/901925

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type) to split the values and use the `metavar` argument to give a better description for the value:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--arg', nargs='*', type=lambda text: text.split('=', maxsplit=1), metavar='PARAM-NAME=PARAM-VALUE', help='Some other parameters')
args = parser.parse_args()
args.arg = {k: v for k,v in args.arg}
```

Which produces:

```
usage: [-h] [--arg [PARAM-NAME=PARAM-VALUE [PARAM-NAME=PARAM-VALUE ...]]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --arg [PARAM-NAME=PARAM-VALUE [PARAM-NAME=PARAM-VALUE ...]]
                        Some other parameters
```

If you wanted to you could avoid the "postprocessing" step to build the dictionary by using a custom [`Action` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action-classes). But it seems an overkill to me in this case.

Comment: That's a really neat solution! Would making my own `Action` type allow me to rewrite the metavars to show multiple optional values? Like `A=X [B=Y] [C=Z]`.